# How to sort certain items in an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, list, sorting

I know this question has been asked But I feel mine is a special case. I still haven't been able to figure this out.

So, I need to sort Employee Objects by their **Age** if they are in departments ***Information Systems or Account***.

However, I cannot get the code to **just** sort Employee's in departments Information Systems or Accoutning, how would I specify just to sort them by age and just print out the rest?.

Here is all relevant code:

**Employee Class:**

```
public class Employee {

private String name;
private int age;
private String department;

public String getDept(){
    return department;
}//end dept

public void setDept(String dept){
    this.department = dept;
}//end

public String getName(){
    return name;
}//end name

public void setName(String n){
    this.name = n;
}//end

public int getAge(){
    return age;
}//end age

public void setAge(int a){
    this.age = a;
}//end



  public String toString(){

      return name + " " + age + " " + department;
  }//end to string


public Employee (String n,int age,String dept){

    this.name = n;
    this.age = age;
    this.department = dept;

}//end employee
}//end class
```

**Department Class:**

```
import java.util.*;






public class Department implements Comparator<Employee>  {

@Override
public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2){

    return  o1.getAge() - o2.getAge();

}//end method

 }//end departmen
```

**Main Method Class:**

```
import java.util.*;



public class Company  {


public static void main(String [] args){


    PrimeAgeChecker p = new PrimeAgeChecker();
    ArrayList<Employee> test = new ArrayList<Employee>();


    test.add(new Employee("Counting Guru",55,"Accounting"));
    test.add(new Employee("Counting Pro",45,"Accounting"));
    test.add(new Employee("Counting Savvy",40,"Accounting"));
    test.add(new Employee("Counting Novice",25,"Accounting"));
    test.add(new Employee("Sales Guru",50,"Marketing"));
    test.add(new Employee("Sales Pro",48,"Marketing"));
    test.add(new Employee("Sales Savvy",38,"Marketing"));
    test.add(new Employee("Hiring Guru",58,"Human Resrouces"));
    test.add(new Employee("Hiring Pro",47,"Human Resrouces"));
    test.add(new Employee("Hacking Pro",47,"Information Systems"));
    test.add(new Employee("Hacking Guru",51,"Information Systems"));
    test.add(new Employee("Hacking Savvy",38,"Information Systems"));
    test.add(new Employee("Hacking Novice",23,"Information Systems"));


    for(Employee i: test){
    if(i.getDept().equals("Information Systems") ||      i.getDept().equals("Accounting")){
        Collections.sort(test, new Department());
        System.out.println(i + " " + p.isPrime(i));
    }//end 
      else{
          System.out.println(i + " " + p.isPrime(i));
      }





}//end main
}//end company
```

Comment: Can you show your expected sorted output for a small set of input ? I can understand what you are saying but want to confirm.

Comment: Sure, Look at the main method class: I'd it to sort where Employee objects have the parameters (String, integer, "Accounting") and sort the Employee objects that have the parameters (String,integer,"Information Systems"). I do not want to sort the other objects that have "Marketing" or "Human Resources" as the last parameter.

Comment: No - I am asking for an example of a sorted output. Not the criteria in words please.

Answer (score 0):

try this example, i left the PrimeAgeCheck out:

```
package de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager;

    import de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager.comparators.AgeComparator;
    import de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager.filter.DepartmentFilter;
    import de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager.filter.utils.FilterUtils;
    import de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager.model.Employee;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

    public class CompanyManager {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

            employees.add(new Employee("Counting Guru", 55, "Accounting"));
            employees.add(new Employee("Counting Pro", 45, "Accounting"));
            employees.add(new Employee("Counting Savvy", 40, "Accounting"));
            employees.add(new Employee("Counting Novice", 25, "Accounting"));
            employees.add(new Employee("Sales Guru", 50, "Marketing"));
            employees.add(new Employee("Sales Pro", 48, "Marketing"));
            employees.add(new Employee("Sales Savvy", 38, "Marketing"));
            employees.add(new Employee("Hiring Guru", 58, "Human Resrouces"));
            employees.add(new Employee("Hiring Pro", 47, "Human Resrouces"));
            employees.add(new Employee("Hacking Pro", 47, "Information Systems"));
            employees.add(new Employee("Hacking Guru", 51, "Information Systems"));
            employees.add(new Employee("Hacking Savvy", 38, "Information Systems"));
            employees.add(new Employee("Hacking Novice", 23, "Information Systems"));

            for(Employee employee : employees) {
                System.out.println(employee);
            }

            List<String> filterDepartsments = new ArrayList<>();
            filterDepartsments.add("Accounting");
            filterDepartsments.add("Information Systems");

            List<Employee> applyFilter = FilterUtils.applyFilter(employees, new DepartmentFilter("Accounting", "Information Systems"));

            System.out.println("filtered list");
            for(Employee employee : applyFilter) {
                System.out.println(employee);
            }

            Collections.sort(applyFilter, new AgeComparator());
            System.out.println("sorted list");
            for(Employee employee : applyFilter) {
                System.out.println(employee);
            }
        }

    }
```

Employee

```
package de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager.model;


public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String department;

    public Employee(final String name, final int age, final String department) {
        this.name       = name;
        this.age        = age;
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ", " + age + ", " + department;
    }

}
```

IFilter Interface

```
package de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager.filter;

public interface IFilter<T> {

    public boolean accept(T value);
}
```

simple Departmentfilter

```
package de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager.filter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DepartmentFilter<String> implements IFilter<String>{

    private final String acceptedDepartment;
    private final String acceptedDepartment2;

    public DepartmentFilter(final String department, final String department2) {
        this.acceptedDepartment = department;
        this.acceptedDepartment2= department2;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean accept(String value) {
        return acceptedDepartment.equals(value) || acceptedDepartment2.equals(value);
    }

}
```

AgeComparator

```
package de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager.comparators;

import de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager.model.Employee;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Employee>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {

        return Integer.valueOf(o1.getAge()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.getAge()));
    }

}
```

FilterUtils class

```
package de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager.filter.utils;

import de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager.filter.IFilter;
import de.professional_webworkx.blog.companymanager.model.Employee;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FilterUtils {

    private static final List<Employee> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static List<Employee> applyFilter(final List<Employee> list, final IFilter filter) {

        for(Employee e : list) {
            if(filter.accept(e.getDepartment())) {
                filteredList.add(e);
            }
        }

        return filteredList;
    }
}
```

Sample output

```
Counting Guru, 55, Accounting
Counting Pro, 45, Accounting
Counting Savvy, 40, Accounting
Counting Novice, 25, Accounting
Sales Guru, 50, Marketing
Sales Pro, 48, Marketing
Sales Savvy, 38, Marketing
Hiring Guru, 58, Human Resrouces
Hiring Pro, 47, Human Resrouces
Hacking Pro, 47, Information Systems
Hacking Guru, 51, Information Systems
Hacking Savvy, 38, Information Systems
Hacking Novice, 23, Information Systems
filtered list
Counting Guru, 55, Accounting
Counting Pro, 45, Accounting
Counting Savvy, 40, Accounting
Counting Novice, 25, Accounting
Hacking Pro, 47, Information Systems
Hacking Guru, 51, Information Systems
Hacking Savvy, 38, Information Systems
Hacking Novice, 23, Information Systems
sorted list
Hacking Novice, 23, Information Systems
Counting Novice, 25, Accounting
Hacking Savvy, 38, Information Systems
Counting Savvy, 40, Accounting
Counting Pro, 45, Accounting
Hacking Pro, 47, Information Systems
Hacking Guru, 51, Information Systems
Counting Guru, 55, Accounting
```

Maybe this helps you.
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this to Your Model 

@Override
    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Employee employee = (Employee) arg0;
        if(employee.getAge() == 10 && this.getAge() == 10 ){

            return this.getDepartment().compareTo(employee.getDepartment());
        } 
        return 0;
    }
```

but this will work only if all the entries which you want to sort are together.
And please change the fields on which you want it to be sorted.